# How to deploy the war file generated by maven on tomcat using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have got a war file generated using Maven and it works perfectly fine when i manually deploy it on the tomcat server.

However, the war file was generated using Maven on eclipse and when i try deploying this on the server using eclipse, it just doesn't act. The tomcat server starts perfectly fine. What I do is : Right click on the Tomcat Server 7.0, then Add/Remove Project and add it to the server.

The problem is when I deploy and publish it on the server and nothing happens after that.

On trying to access it, it says - **The required resource is not found**

Comment: you added project to server and started server, what was the error log ?

Comment: no error log on the console. All fine till server started up

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't deploy the WAR. Instead, it knows how Tomcat works and deploys the exploded WAR.

The next step is to look into the `webapps/` folder of Tomcat to make sure Eclipse really has deployed something.

If that looks ok, you need to look into the Tomcat log to see why it doesn't like the deployed web app.

Most of the time, there is old code which is somehow stuck in Tomcat, so Tomcat can't undeploy  the old version. If that's the case, stop Tomcat, delete the app manually and try again.

Comment: It hasnt deployed anything yet. Its not yet in the webapps folder

Comment: Open the "Error Log View". That's Eclipse's internal error log - *not the console!* Do you see anything in there when you try to deploy?

Comment: There is nothing in there as well

Comment: Having more doubts around this now - Do i need to mention about pom.xml in web.xml or vice versa? Do i need to update any settings.xml? I see the jars should be under WEB-INF/lib. Does that hold true for maven projects? I haven't done anything as these. All I have done is: Create a maven project, add dependencies to pom.xml, convert project to facets, create tomcat 7 server. Maven install created a war which works fine. But when I do Add/Remove project on tomact server, it doesnt work. I have already spent a lot of time on this. Looking forward for good pointers. Thanks!

Comment: There is a plugin for m2e with makes it visible to WTP: https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/ Installing it should help. Maven manages `WEB-INF/lib/` for you. m2e-wtp should help Eclipse see what should go in there during deployment. But since nothing gets deployed, you must have a problem earlier.

Comment: That said, I've given up on things like WTP and deploying web apps from Eclipse. I use embedded web servers or things like the [Jetty Maven Plugin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) since they are much, much more reliable. And faster. Did I mention more reliable? Much more reliable. You just have to get used to remote debugging.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I did install the plugin and created new project again from scratch. Didnt help much either.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the m2e-wtp video?

Comment: yes, i did. all it says is **The requested resource is not available.** when i try accessing the application

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of WTP and deploying Java apps to web servers. Does the Jetty Maven Plugin work?

Comment: Just noticed this: The lib folder under the Deployed Resources/webapp/WEB-INF folder is empty. Will that be the cause? If so, how can i get my libraries there>

Comment: Stop looking at `WEB-INF/lib/`. That's step 25. Step 1 isn't working. If it's not deploying anything, why should there be anything in `WEB-INF/lib/`??

Answer (score 0):

There were certain jars required in specific versions for the application to work. I was usin the maven supported versions. I have got it to work adding them directly in Tomcat's lib folder for time being and the application now works. (Anyways i need to look to get them configured now on the maven)

Also, i guess installing the plugin for m2e - eclipse.org/m2e-wtp helped as well. Thanks @Aaron Digulla for the inputs.